# PHP Proper way to redirect form actions

Tags: php, http-status-code-301, http-status-codes

I have a `PHP` form action on login `/actions/login.php`. It checks everything and the credentials, and if valid, sets the proper cookies and simply does:

```
header("Location: /dashboard.php", true, 302);
```

Is this the best way to do this? In Chrome developer tools, when I inspect the requests, I see:

```
Request URL:https://mydomain.com/actions/login.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Moved Temporarily
```

Is there a more elegant solution instead of sending a `302 redirect`?

Comment: Do you need an actual redirect? Can you for example display the dashboard.php page on the page you submitted to? Or could you post the data to dashboard.php, and perform the check there, then redirect if the login fails?

Comment: This is more of a general queestion, i.e. all my form actions when they complete do: `header("Location: /some-page-here.php", true, 302);`

Comment: Yes thats the best and afaik the only way to redirect with php.

Answer (score 0):

Yes is the best way, also remember call exit(); or die(); function to avoid execute extra code after redirection

```
header("Location: /dashboard.php", true, 302);
exit();
```